# Need to display reports in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

Need to display reports in salesforce1. I found dashboards but i am unable to  add reports

Answer (score 2):

Reports are available since the Summer14 update of the mobile app. Click on any dashboard to see the first 100 rows of the report. Note: this is not available for the complex 'matrix' and 'joined' type of reports.

See http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_analytics_drill_to_report.htm

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Willem Mulder answer. You need to create a Dashboard from your report to use it in SF1. Once you do, your SF1 user can click on it and the report will be displayed. The only way to access them is through clicking on the Dashboard icon related to the report.

One important limitation is that Matrix and Joined reports are not supported at this time in SF1. Only Tabular and Summary Reports are supported at this point. You can still drill down further within reports to see even more detail by swiping, but again only for the 1st 100 records in the report.